# Removing Folders htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am fairly new to htaccess regex. I am trying to figure out how to redirect the following using htaccess rules.

I have a site that has the following structure /cat/cat/c/cat/. What I am trying to do is redirect the /cat/cat/c/cat/ to /c/cat/. I have tried the following but it doesn't appear to be working -

`RewriteRule ^/(.+)/c/(.+)  /c/$2   [R=301,NC,L]`

I have also tried a rule that I have found on here and that also doesn't appear to be working -

`RewriteCond {%REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*)/c/(.*)
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /c/$2 [R=301,L]`

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you want the URL to show in the browser when you visit your site?

Comment: Hi Panama, the url should go from www.example.com/subfolder/subfolder/c/subfolder/ to www.example.com/c/subfolder/